# I am having a trouble with an algorithm for assinging syllable boundaries in Python

Tags: python, string, list, nlp

could you help me please?

I am trying to desing an algorithm that assings the syllable boundaries for any given string of consonanats and vowels 'CVCCVCCVCC'. These strings are stored in a list that may run into hundred of thousands or even million of itmes in length. However, it seems that I did not understand handling lists properly and that is why I am getting this trouble. After composing the code, I click "Run" the module, and Python shell restarts, raising no syntax error. However, when I test the code, it returns an empty list. The code is here. Could you please tell me what is the wrong with my algorithm? I am getting really disappointed.

Thanks in advance for kind help!

```
def assing_boundaries(L):

    """ (List of str -> List of str)

    Assings the syllable boundaries for a given string of Syllable      Templates, with the output meeting the two conditions given below:
Condition1: item[2:] != 'CC'
Condition2: item[:-2] !='C.C'

    >>> assing_boundaries(['CVCCVCC', 'CVCCV:C'])
    ['CVC.CVCC', 'CVC.CV:C']   
    """


    boundary = []
    i = 0

    for item in L:
        for char in item:
            for i in range(len(item) - 1):
                if item[i] == 'CC':
                    char = 'C.C'
                    i = i + 1
                    boundary = boundary.append(item)


    return boundary
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your loop is wrong. You test `if item[i] == 'CC'`, but `item[i]` can only ever be a single character.
2. `boundary = boundary.append(item)` is wrong, because `.append` returns `None`. Just do `boundary.append(item)`.

Simpler yet, why not just do `return [item.replace('CC', 'C.C') for item in L]` instead? You can tweak the list comprehension to filter the list as needed.

Comment: Thank you nneonneo for your kind help. The return statement seems pretty compact and short. Yet, I want to impose a condition on the fuction which is:       if 'CC' occur at the indices item[:2], they should be kept intact. Example, input ['CVCCVCC'] and output should look like this ['CVC.CVCC']. You see, the second occurance of 'CC' which is in the indices item[:-2] should not be replaced.  I have tried to impose this condition, but I could not do it. In fact, I am a beginner in Python. Could you but extend your help in this issue? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `return [item[0] + item[1:-1].replace('CC', 'C.C') + item[-1] for item in L]`?

Comment: nneonneo,      Thank you so much for your kind help again. I have struggled with this code for more than a week, but your help was effective and the code executed properly. Your are so smart. Thank you again!